# Look up table in BIRT

Tags: eclipse, birt, lookup-tables

I have a Birt Dataset that contains some enumeration values. 
e.g.
ID  NAME  ENUM VAL
1   ABC   ENUM_VAL1
2   DEF   ENUM_VAL2

There is another Data Set called enumeration lookup which contains the mapping of Enum values to their respective description.
ID ENUM_VAL ENUM_DESC
1  ENUM_VAL1 Enum value description
2  ENUM_VAL2 Enum value descrption 2

Currently my output table shows the following
ID  NAME  ENUM VAL
1   ABC   ENUM_VAL1
2   DEF   ENUM_VAL2

But instead of enumeration val I want to show the enumeration description. I cannot just go and do a static mapping as the values may change over time and it would be hard to maintain.

What is the proper way to implement lookup tables in BIRT

Comment: If it's SQL we're talking about, then a SQL join is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve it, I created an oracle function to convert Enum value to Enum description as follows

```
 Create or Replace FUNCTION getEnumValue(etype IN VARCHAR2, val IN VARCHAR2) RETURN 
   VARCHAR2 IS
   descrip varchar2(75); 
 BEGIN
   select description into descrip from TABLE_NAME where enumtype = etype and value = val;
 RETURN descrip;
 END;
```

Then in my dataset query called this particular function and passed in required attributes.